Kong ingress controller upstream timeout
How can I change upstream timeout on kong ingress 3.1.x?
Before, (version 2.7.x), I was using this plugin:
apiVersion: configuration.konghq.com/v1
kind: KongPlugin
metadata:
  name: up-timeout
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: kong
  labels:
    global: "true"
plugin: upstream-timeout
config:
  connect_timeout: 30000
  send_timeout: 3600000
  read_timeout: 3600000

I also tried this annotation on service yaml:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: logistics-simulator
  annotations:
    konghq.com/override: kong-timeout
    konghq.com/connect-timeout: 3600000
spec:
    type: ClusterIP
    ports:
    - port: 80 
    selector:
        app: logistics-simulator

but I am getting this error on AKS with yaml code above:

error: unable to decode
“/home/vsts/work/_temp/Service_logistics-simulator_1712325946614”:
json: cannot unmarshal number into Go struct field
ObjectMeta.metadata.annotations of type string
##[error]error: unable to decode “/home/vsts/work/_temp/Service_logistics-simulator_1712325946614”:
json: cannot unmarshal number into Go struct field
ObjectMeta.metadata.annotations of type string


It looks it's an error because the resources are sending JSON/YAML data to the corresponding Kong go service in the backend and it cannot unmarshall it (Expecting something other than a number). I would try putting quotes on the timeout values (strings instead of numbers)
apiVersion: configuration.konghq.com/v1
kind: KongPlugin
metadata:
  name: up-timeout
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: kong
  labels:
    global: "true"
plugin: upstream-timeout
config:
  connect_timeout: "30000"
  send_timeout: "3600000"
  read_timeout: "3600000"

and
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: logistics-simulator
  annotations:
    konghq.com/override: kong-timeout
    konghq.com/connect-timeout: "3600000"
spec:
    type: ClusterIP
    ports:
    - port: 80 
    selector:
        app: logistics-simulator

